# Generate 6 digit number from 000001 to 999999 in Linux

Tags: linux

Is there any command in Linux where I could generate the value 000001 to 999999 and store into a txt file? I know there is a seq command but it creates the value 1 to 999999 instead of 000001 to 999999.

Comment: Add zeros before the first number, until it has the amount of zeros you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
seq -f "%06g" 999999
```

Comment: Better to use `%06.f` instead of `%06g` to avoid switching to exponential notation. For example, `seq -f "%06g" 999999999 999999999` yields `01e+09` instead of `999999999`.